# Creating a txt file in a subfolder while creating the subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a folder and three subfolders. In one of the subfolders, I want create a txt file. So far I can create the folders and subfolders, but the txt file always gets created in the main folder.

```
MD CST1500\a 
MD CST1500\b
MD CST1500\c
\CST1500\a > hostname.txt
```

I want the txt file to be created in subfolder a

```
MD CST1500\a > hostname.txt
MD CST1500\b
MD CST1500\c
```

This also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
MD CST1500\a 
MD CST1500\b
MD CST1500\c
type NUL > CST1500\a\EmptyFile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find more information about batch scripting? I am having trouble finding basic info like what is the % for?

Comment: @Modo https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm   percentage signs are used in multiple ways e.g. to represent command line arguments https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm and as modulus operator https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_operators.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try alternatives

```
echo foobar >CST1500\a\hostname.txt   (file with "foobar\r\n")
echo. >CST1500\a\hostname.txt         (while with "\r\n")
copy nul CST1500\a\hostname.txt       (empty file)
```

`MD CST1500\a > hostname.txt` redirects the output of `MD CST1500\a` into the file `hostname.txt` in the current directory.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find more information about batch scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Use `For` loop:

In your command line:

```bat
for %i in (a,b,c)do md "%~i" & cd.>"%~fi\%~i.txt"
```

In your batch file:

```bat
@echo off

cd/d "Driver:\Full\Path\To\Folder\CST1500"
for %%i in (a,b,c)do md "%%~i" & cd.>"%%~fi\%%~i.txt"
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)