# Batch file iterates through files after I want it to stop

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I made a batch file that is supposed to put files from one directory into subfolders named 1,2,3 and so on but only if the subfolder has less than 1000 files. I have 1 batch file for each folder and it calls all 100

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
for /f %%f in ('dir /b P:\InstaPics\1\') do set /a count+=1
if %count% geq 1000 exit /b
for /f %%f in ('dir /b P:\InstaPics\') do set jn=%%f && call :sub
:sub 
if %count% geq 1000 exit /b
set /a jnum+=1
robocopy /mov P:\InstaPics\ P:\InstaPics\1\ %jn%
set /a count+=1
if %count% geq 1000 exit /b
:die
```

The problem is after it gets to 1000 it stops copying like it should but it keeps iterating as shown below. Any idea how I can get it to stop? It takes a while to iterate through the other 10,000 files not put in a subfolder yet

[image: Still iterating through files]

Comment: This would be so much easier in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

---

Your variables `%count%`, `%jnum%` and `%jn%`, they don't exist (no value, not accessed) within your function `:sub`

**They existed if you pass them to the variable:**

```bat
call :sub "%file%" "%path%" "string"

:sub
echo\ My variable file is argument #1: %1
echo\ My variable path is argument #2: %2  
echo\ My simple string is argument #3: %3
```

***[It is not enough just to call a function, if inside it you will make use of variables

(already defined), it is necessary to pass these variables so that they are accessed/used

within the function...](https://superuser.com/a/1688587/969781)***

---

With the smallest possible change to your original code, and using/passing arguments to your label/function `:sub`, it would be:

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1

for /f %%f in ('dir /b P:\InstaPics\1\') do set /a count+=1
if %count% geq 1000 exit /b

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b P:\InstaPics\') do call :sub %count% "%%~f" && set /a count+=1

:sub 
if "%~1" == "" (endlocal && echo\done!)

if %~1 lss 1000 (
     set /a jnum+=1
     robocopy /mov P:\InstaPics\ P:\InstaPics\1\ "%~2"
    ) else endlocal && echo\done!
    
exit /b
    
:die
rem: continue... ???
```

---

- An alternative without using label/function for main task:

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pushd "P:\InstaPics\1\." && set /a _jn=0,_cnt=0

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a:-d .\* ^| find /v /c ""'
    )do if %%f geq 1000 (popd & endlocal & exit /b)else set "_cnt=%%~f"

for %%f in ("P:\InstaPics\*")do set /a "_jn+=1,_cnt+=1" && (
     robocopy /mov /l /njh /njs "%%~dpf\." .\ "%%~nxf"
     if !_jn! geq 1000 goto %:^)
    )

%:^)
popd & timeout /t 5 | echo\!_cnt!/!_jn! & endlocal & exit /b
```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[Set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
- **[`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**
- **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `!Expand_RunTime_Variable!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**
- **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/1670957/batch-for-loop-not-recognizing-its-own-variable/1674454#1674454)**